# Is this add or subtraction?

Tags: javascript

I am really confused by this. For example `var a = +"3" -"2"` is this subtraction or adding? To me this is adding negative value on to number 3.  Can someone please clarify this for me, my brain is starting to hurt.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) - minus will convert the operand to number.

Comment: The addition operator is “overloaded” and can do more than addition.

Comment: This is why I *hate* using `+` to convert a string to a number -- it doesn't express intent.  Just use `Number()` people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into consideration [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the first `+` (called "unary plus", precedence 17) is turning the `"3"` string into a number, after which the `-` (precedence 14) converts the expressions on either side to numbers and subtraction occurs:

```
var a = +"3" -"2"
// equivalent to:
var a = (+"3") -"2"
var a = (3) -"2"
// Subtraction casts both sides to numbers before it occurs
// Left side is already a number
var a = 3 -2
var a = 1
```

Comment: Isn't - converting 2 to a negative number value?

Comment: If there's an expression on the left-hand side of the `-`, the `-` is interpreted to be subtraction (because it wouldn't really make sense otherwise). If there is *no* expression on the left-hand side of the `-`, eg `const num = -"3"`, then yes, the `-` would act as unary negation, casting the `'3'` to a number and turning it negative.

Comment: Aha, ok. The part that was confusing me is that when `var a = +"3"` and look it up in console log i get a number. Same goes for `var a = -"3"`. So only thing that makes logic to me at that point is that negative value was added, was not aware of that it applies only if there is no left-hand side expression. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Subtraction

The first '+' is a unary operator, while '-' is a binary operator.
Therefore the operation is subtraction.

```js
var a = +"3" -"2"
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` for `+"3"` is an [Unary plus (MDN: Arithmetic operators)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_2):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already.

So  `+"3"` converts the string `3` to the number `3`, resulting in `3-"2"`.

The `-` in `3 - "2"`  is not a unary operator, because it has a value on its left sides, so it is a [subtraction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Subtraction)

In `3+-"2"` the `-` would be a unary operator,  converting the `"2"` to a negative number.